# Reload java method in JSP after every two seconds

Tags: java, jsp

I have a java method in a class and I want to call this method in JSP after every 2 seconds. Also, want to save the value returned by this method to a variable in JSP.

valuepass.java

```
package docker;
public class valuepass{
    public static int value=0;
    public static int count(){
        if ( value >= 99 ){
            System.out.println(value);
            return value; //or throw exception, whatever
        }
        else{
             System.out.println(value);
             return value++;
        }
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
import="java.util.* , java.io.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="docker.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var auto = setInterval(    function ()
     {
          <%= valuepass.count() %>;
     }, 2000); // refresh every 2000 milliseconds
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<font face="verdana" size="4px">
Auto Reload Part Of Webpage Every 2 Seconds In Java-Jsp-jQuery
</font><br><br>
   <img src="images/java4s.png"><br><br>
   <div id="score"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But the index.jsp returns the same value every time but in java code, I am incrementing the value on every call.

The output I am getting is 0 and on reloading the page every time it gives incremented value like 1, 2, 3 ......

What I want is 0123456789...

I think I have some problem in scriptlets calling the valuepass.count

Also, i to store the value returned by valuepass.count in a variable so that I can use it in JSP.

Comment: You need to understand that once the javascript starts, the JSP is done. So your html code generated from the JSP contains `var auto = setInterval(    function ()
     {
          1;
     }, 2000);` and that's it

Comment: So you either do that in javascript or communicate from javascript to your server (where your JSP is executed) to get that value.

Comment: You can't do this. You need to AJAX it

Comment: If you are happy with always refreshing the page, you don't need Ajax. (but the timer doesnt make any sense) If you don't want to always refresh your page you need to go with the solution suggested by Jonathan. However if you would like to have a String like 0123456... you need to create the String in the backend side, in your solution make it static and you should append always the incremented value to the String. (Something like the following. valueString += value // what is valuestring = valuestring + value)

Comment: Well, you could simply reload the page passing the current value into parameter. So your `count()` would be a simple `inc(int value)`. Reloading the page every 2sec. This would let you use JSP (if the point is to learn JSP).

Answer (score 0):

In java class,use `session.setAttribute("value",countValue);` where countValue's initial value is 0 and it is the value that is loaded when the java method is called. THen the session will have the value . So if you again call the method,use `String countValue = session.getAttribute("value");` to get the value from session.Add `1` with session value and again set it to the session `session.setAttribute("value",countValue);` SO session will have the value permanently. If you want to remove the session value use `session.removeAttribute("value");`. Call this session anywhere you want in your project.